# Wordpress fetching image title based on background url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I'm currently trying to add the image title to the slideshow media widget in elementor pro through the code attached here :

```
jQuery('.elementor-carousel-image').attr('id','slideshowImage')

var slideshowDiv = document.querySelectorAll("#slideshowImage");

for (var i = 0; i<slideshowDiv.length; i++) {
    var content = document.createTextNode("Title");
  slideshowDiv[i].appendChild(content);
}
```

As of now it is able to show the text "Title" at the top of every image. However i'm looking to attach the actual image title in the wordpress media. Is there a way to achieve this? The slideshow shows images based on the background property in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it through fetching the title through background image url, and appending the title to a  tag, followed by some css

```
/***********
ADDING TITLE TO BOTTOM OF EVERY image
***********/

function addImageTitle(e) {
    
    const imageCarousels = document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-carousel-image');
    
    imageCarousels.forEach(imageCarousel => {
        
        // To fetch image title
        let imageURL = window.getComputedStyle(imageCarousel,false).backgroundImage;
        let imageTitle = imageURL.slice(imageURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1,imageURL.lastIndexOf('.')).split('-').join(' ');
        
        //To append title to image carousel
        let titleElement = document.createElement("h1");
        let titleText = document.createTextNode(imageTitle);
        titleElement.appendChild(titleText);
        
        imageCarousel.append(titleElement);
        
        
    })

}

addImageTitle();
```

CSS

```
.elementor-carousel-image>h1{
    font-size:30px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    color:white;
    background:black;
    padding:10px;
}
.elementor-fit-aspect-ratio.elementor-carousel-image>h1{
    font-size:0px;
    background:none;
}
```